# Circular path based on time (sun's path in sky)

Tags: trigonometry, circles, coordinate-systems

I'm working on a video game and have coordinates:

- `z` is West (negative) and East (positive)
- `y` is elevation

I'm trying to find an equation for each part of the sun's position (z, y) so that it rotates around a center `(0, 0)` based on the time.

At `minute = 0`, it will be rising in the East (positive Z coordinate), continue in the air, updating based on time, until it reaches `minute = 3`, where it will set in the West (negative Z coordinate).

- `minute = 0`: `(3000, 0)`
- `minute = 1.5`: `(0, 3000)`
- `minute = 3`: `(-3000, 0)`

If you have any ideas, they're all appreciated!

[circle diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvPxY.png)

Comment: Do you need to vary all 3 coordinates? i.e. can't you have it rotating around the centre in a plane?

Comment: Just use a rotation matrix for the sun heading east to west, and another rotation matrix to adjust whichever inclination you want

Comment: @mrnovice you're right, I don't need to worry about the x-coords. Just z and y. I edited my question slightly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve what you want, just consider the equation $z^{2}+y^{2} = 3000^{2}$

Let $y = r\sin \theta, z = r\cos \theta$

Now we want it to vary with period $3$ rather than period $2\pi$.

So at $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$, $t=1.5$

Therefore let $t=\frac{3\theta}{\pi}$

So we get $\theta = \frac{\pi t}{3}$

$\Rightarrow y = r\sin(\frac{\pi t}{3}), z = r \cos (\frac{\pi t}{3})$

So let $r = 3000$

Then our equation fits the first equation: $z^{2}+y^{2} = 3000^{2}(\sin(\frac{\pi t}{3})^{2} + \cos(\frac{\pi t}{3})^{2}) = 3000^{2}\cdot 1 = 3000^{2}$ as required.

So the solution is:

$y = 3000 \sin(\frac{\pi t}{3}), z = 3000 \cos (\frac{\pi t}{3})$